# Storyboard changes aren't saved

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I made some changes in my storyboard, basically just changed the background color, yet when i run the app the changes aren't made in the simulator. I cleaned the project, deleted the app from the simulator, restarted the simulator and restarted xcode but it doesn't work. How can I apply the changes?

Comment: Show us what have u tried? Show us the story board and the property u modified and also show us the corresponding viewController associated. Its very difficult to guess without any of these information

Comment: It's possible that the color was under something else opaque.  Use the 'Debug View Hierarchy' option to look at your views while the app is running.

Comment: You should make sure the storyboard element you changed is connected to a ViewController within the application.